# Specialize member function that returns void and have no parameters

Tags: c++, template-specialization, class-members

Suppose i have this function:

```
class A {
    template<class Collider> void Init();
};
```

Can i specialize it for Sphere and Box?

I call this function from other template function, so it is not easy to just use InitForSphere and InitForBox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
template<>
void A::Init<Box>() {}

template<>
void A::Init<Sphere>() {}
```

call it like

```
A a;
a.Init<Box>();
```